# want to update a certain field on mysql database

Tags: mysql

i want to update one of the field on my table using the sum from the other table. Bellow are query but not working.

```
UPDATE ehap
SET this_month = SUM(beneficiaries.AMOUNT)
JOIN beneficiaries on beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id
WHERE 
    beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id AND
    MONTHNAME(beneficiaries.disbursement_date) = MONTHNAME(CURDATE())
```

this_month is a field from ehap table, the other table is name beneficiaries. I want to get the total of those amount from beneficiary per ehap and save it to this_month field of ehap table.

I hope you guys understand my question.

Comment: You can use a nested select. Update ehap SET this_month = (SELECT ...your select  statement for sum...) WHERE ....

Comment: SET clause must posess after complete data source (FROM .. JOIN). And use grouping subquery instead of direct `beneficiaries` usage.

Comment: This isn't MySQL update syntax

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE ehap
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT,
              EHAP_ID 
       FROM beneficiaries 
       WHERE MONTHNAME(disbursement_date) = MONTHNAME(CURDATE())
       GROUP BY EHAP_ID ) beneficiaries
SET ehap.this_month = beneficiaries.AMOUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, I was able to fix it, please see the query below:

```
UPDATE ehap c

INNER JOIN (    select ehap.id, SUM(beneficiaries.AMOUNT) AS Total2
    from ehap
    JOIN beneficiaries on beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id
    where beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id and MONTHNAME(beneficiaries.disbursement_date) = MONTHNAME(CURDATE())
    GROUP by ehap.incident_name ) y ON c.id = y.id

INNER JOIN (    select ehap.id, SUM(beneficiaries.AMOUNT) AS Total
    from ehap
    JOIN beneficiaries on beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id
    where beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id and MONTHNAME(beneficiaries.disbursement_date) != MONTHNAME(CURDATE())
    GROUP by ehap.incident_name ) x ON c.id = x.id

INNER JOIN ( select ehap.id, COUNT(*) as total_number
    from ehap
    JOIN beneficiaries on beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id
    where beneficiaries.EHAP_ID = ehap.id
    GROUP by ehap.incident_name ) w ON c.id = w.id


SET c.this_month = y.Total2, c.previous = x.total, c.w_payment = w.total_number, c.on_process = c.no_benef - w.total_number, c.balance
= c.amount - (x.total + y.Total2)
```